# Octave C++ API: addpath

Tags: c++, octave

I can run the example - found [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2009-04/msg00005.html) - to execute an octave function from c++.
This works if the function file is located in the same directory in which the c++ code is executed.

If the function file is located in a different path, it can be loaded with:
`octave_function *fun = load_fcn_from_file("/Path/exampleOctaveFunction.m");`
This would mean, that I have to load each individual function that I want to use.

Is there a method, like `addpath` in Octave, available in the C++ API to add a full directory? Or can I even set the working directory of the Octave execution to use relative paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at this again, the solution is really obvious.
Just use the Octave `addpath` function.

So instead of loading a function by its path and then executing it,

```
octave_function *fun = load_fcn_from_file("/Path/exampleOctaveFunction.m")
feval(octave_function)
```

do

```
octave_value_list arg;
arg(0) = "Path";
feval("addpath", arg);
```

Now the function (and all other functions in `Path`) can be loaded in the common manner

```
feval("exampleOctaveFunction")
```

Combine the call to `addpath` with `genpath` to add all subdirectories of a given path.